# How to check if database row value has changed before doing a fill on a dataset

Tags: ado.net, dataset, dataadapter, optimistic-concurrency

When I try to update a database with some modified values in a dataset, a concurrence exception doesn't raise if i change manually some values in the database after the fill method on the dataset is performed. (I only get the exception if I delete a row manually and then I try call the method update of data adapter).

How should I check if I have a "dirty read" on my dataset?.

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/wPXuhzVy This is something similar I do... How should I check before updating if the original value of a row is different from the current value of the database (What is called a "dirty read"). I thought I would just get a concurrence exception but seems like my assumption is wrong.

Comment: See my answer. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You have several options.

- Keeping a copy of the original entity set to compare against and make
  the is dirty determination at the point you need to know whether it's
  dirty.
- Checking the datarow's rowstate property and if Modified compare
  the values in the Current and Original DataRowVersions. If the second
  change makes the value the same as the original then you could call
  RejectChanges, however that would reject all changes on the row. You 
  will have to manually track each field since the dataset only keeps
  per-row or per-table changes.